# How to disable foreign key and primary key constraint temporarily in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I have one table that has two fields. The structure is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE raw_links
(
  value_id bigint NOT NULL,
  raw_id integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT raw_links_pk PRIMARY KEY (raw_id, dp_id),
  CONSTRAINT raw_fk FOREIGN KEY (raw_id)
      REFERENCES raw_data (raw_data_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
```

I have to delete 5 million records from this table. For that I want to disable both constraints so that deletion will be faster. After deletion I want to create both constraints.

Comment: You need to drop and re-create them.

Comment: Ok i will drop then i will delete my 50 lakhs records .After when i will recreate then will it throw exception ???Because there is a chance of mismatch of records between this table and raw_data table..

Answer (score 2):

You can do `ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT raw_links_pk` and the same for `raw_fk`.

After you delete the records, first do a `VACUUM ANALYZE raw_links` (or `VACUUM FULL raw_links` if you want to reclaim disk space), to update the table statistics.

Then finally rebuild the constraints with `ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT ...`.

Comment: Ok i will drop then i will delete my 50 lakhs records .After when i will recreate then will it throw exception ???Because there is a chance of mismatch of records between this table and raw_data table..

Comment: That can only happen when there are updates on `raw_data.raw_data_id` while you are doing this. In that case you can't drop the constraints and should just do it the slow way with constraints in place.

Answer (score 1):

For the example.
Schema: source, Table: finalsales, Constrait: finalsales_pkey, Column: order_id.

--Disable Primary Key

```
ALTER TABLE source."finalsales" DROP CONSTRAINT finalsales_pkey;
```

--Enable Primary Key

```
ALTER TABLE source."finalsales"
ADD CONSTRAINT finalsales_pkey PRIMARY KEY ( order_id );
```