# How to temporarily drop constraints and indexes of a table in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I need to run some sync jobs, where a curtain part of table needs to be synced with the output of bigQuery query. In order to do this I do the following steps:

1. Create a temporary table like the target table with primary keys and constraints
2. Insert the csv data into the temporary table
3. Upsert the target table with the data from the temporary table
4. Delete data in the target table matching the filter of in the target table that is not part of the temporary table

In order to help the performance of the temporary table inserts I want to insert without the primary keys and constraints and then apply them later. I need to apply them since it is a very important sanity check of the data in bigQuery and the query planner needs these indexes in order to perform later operations fast enoght.

I can drop all constraints using [Drop all of a table's constraints in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77253255/drop-all-of-a-tables-constraints-in-postgres), but I need to be able to fetch the code for the constraints to afterwards reintroduce them.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Why not just disable them?

Comment: Deleting and creating constraints IS disabling.  I have 10 different tables synced this way, so I need the code to be stable and robust. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36734920/how-to-disable-foreign-key-and-primary-key-constraint-temporarily-in-postgresql

Comment: Why don't you create a migration for dropping constraints and indexes, and then return to the precedent version of your DB.

Comment: please read: "but I need to be able to fetch the code for the constraints to afterwards reintroduce them. Can somebody help me with this?"

Comment: `pg_dump -d <the_db> -s -t <target_table> -f target_table_schema.sql`. You now have the target table schema. Use the CREATE TABLE portion for step 1) and the PK/constraint commands for a step between steps 2) and 3).

Comment: From the description, it appears that the affected constraints/indexes are only on the temporary/staging tables and not on the target tables. If so, then the simplest approach is to create the temporary tables using `LIKE` without incuding constraints and indexes, populate the temporary tables from the CSV files, and then query the PostgreSQL system views to get the target tables' constraint and index definitions and use those to construct the necessary SQL to replicate the constraints  and indexes on the temporary tables.

Comment: @JohnH, I am not following as your comment is internally inconsistent: a) *... it appears that the affected constraints/indexes are only on the temporary/staging tables and not on the target tables.* b) *... then query the PostgreSQL system views to get the target tables' constraint and index definitions ...*

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, my comment is not internally inconsistent. The OP specifically mentioned creating temporary tables like the target tables (including constraints) and then dropping the constraints on the temporary tables prior to loading the data into them. My suggestion is to wait to create the constraints on the temprary tables until after data has been loaded into them. Since the OP doesn't mention dropping the contraints on the **target** tables, the system views have the necessary details to generate SQL to create corresponding constraints on the **temporary** tables.